# Why does a linear regression in time series forecasting does not provide a line in predictions?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, time-series, forecasting

I'm reading the TensorFlow Time Series forecasting Tutorial [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) trying to perform my own time series prediction. However, specifically on single-shot models section for multiple time steps, the Linear model is implemented as a Dense layer without the activation. I have two questions regarding this:

1. In my understanding, this is equivalent as a linear regression. Is that correct?
2. Why does the model doesn't provide a line as the predictions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reg.1) Yes, this would be a linear model. Reg 2) What is the exact figure you are referring to? If this would be an AR1 process ($t_{-1}$ as input to predict $t$) than you would not expect a (straight) line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model